# I need to display the specific format file in real time scenario

Tags: python, ipython

I am using the below python codes to display the batch files generated in
   a specified directory in real time scenario.When you run this in IPython,
   this displays nothing when then batch files are not generated.When the
   batch files are generated,this displays the output FILE1 READY and
   clears the screen and then displays FILE2 READY.I need to display all the 
   batch files generated together in vertical list. Could any one help me in
   this

```
import os,time
dir=os.getcwd()

def doo():

   while True:

      for filename in os.listdir(dir):
          if filename.endswith('.bat'):
             print filename+' READY \n'
             time.sleep(1)
             os.system('cls')
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question but can't you just move `os.system('cls')` outside the for loop?

Comment: This runs as an infinite loop.Please run this in IPython console.

Comment: I understand that it's in infinite loop but I don't understand your question

Comment: I think SirParselot is right. What you are currently doing is printing the filename + READY, then clearing the screen for every file. Instead, you should print each file, **then** clear the screen, i.e. move the `cls` outside the for-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form `files` sting in `for` loop  and print it after `for` loop ends:

```
files = '' 
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
      if filename.endswith('.bat'):
         files += filename + ' READY \n'
         time.sleep(1)
         os.system('cls')
print files
```

Comment: @AndiryIvaneyko:This is what I was looking for.The screen becomes empty the moment the batch files are deleted/moved and screen displays the file names  in vertical series when the batch files are generated.